# form fields are not getting set if the values are unchanged in react

Tags: reactjs, forms

In my edit form, I am getting default values from an object, soo that when the user clicks on the edit button the values are prefilled. But if the user clicks on the save button without changing fields it's returning empty object as I am writing it on **onChange** method.
How do I send values of the fields as it is if it is unchanged

this is my edit form code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import CloseIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Close";
import { Slide, Grid, TextField, Container } from "@material-ui/core";
import { editAddressAction } from "../../store/actions/UIactions";
import { updateAddressAction } from "../../store/actions/userDetailActions";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    appBar: {
        position: "relative",
    },
    title: {
        marginLeft: theme.spacing(2),
        flex: 1,
    },
    newSection: {
        marginTop: "1rem",
    },
    innerSection: {
        padding: "1rem",
    },
    text: {
        color: "grey",
    },
    hText: {
        color: "grey",
        fontSize: 18,
    },
    form: {
        width: "100%", // Fix IE 11 issue.
        marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    },
}));

const Transition = React.forwardRef(function Transition(props, ref) {
    return <Slide direction="up" ref={ref} {...props} />;
});

const EditAddressDialog = (props) => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState("");
    
    const handleClose = () => {
        props.popClose(false);
    };

    const handleChangeValues = (e) => {
        setValues({
            ...values,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        });
    };

    const handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(values)
        props.updateAddress(values, props.addressData.id);
        props.popClose(false);
    };
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <div>
            <Dialog
                fullScreen
                open={props.editAddressData}
                onClose={handleClose}
                TransitionComponent={Transition}
            >
                <AppBar className={classes.appBar}>
                    <Toolbar>
                        <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
                            Edit Address
                        </Typography>
                        <IconButton
                            edge="start"
                            color="inherit"
                            onClick={handleClose}
                            aria-label="close"
                        >
                            <CloseIcon />
                        </IconButton>
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>
                <Container className={classes.newSection}></Container>
                <Container>
                    <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
                        <Grid container justify="space-between">
                            <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                                <Typography style={{ textAlign: "center", color: "grey" }}>
                                    Ensure the address is correct,It will help your vendor to
                                    serve you better
                                </Typography>
                                <TextField
                                    required
                                    variant="filled"
                                    margin="normal"
                                    fullWidth
                                    name="flatNo"
                                    label="Flat/House"
                                    type="text"
                                    onChange={handleChangeValues}
                                    defaultValue={props.addressData.flatNo}
                                />
                                <TextField
                                    required
                                    variant="filled"
                                    margin="normal"
                                    fullWidth
                                    name="complex"
                                    label="Bld./Complex"
                                    type="text"
                                    onChange={handleChangeValues}
                                    defaultValue={props.addressData.complex}
                                />
                                <TextField
                                    required
                                    variant="filled"
                                    margin="normal"
                                    fullWidth
                                    name="area"
                                    label="Area"
                                    type="text"
                                    onChange={handleChangeValues}
                                    defaultValue={props.addressData.area}
                                />
                                <TextField
                                    required
                                    variant="filled"
                                    margin="normal"
                                    fullWidth
                                    name="city"
                                    label="City"
                                    type="text"
                                    onChange={handleChangeValues}
                                    defaultValue={props.addressData.city}
                                />

                                <Button
                                    type="submit"
                                    fullWidth
                                    variant="contained"
                                    color="primary"
                                >
                                    SAVE
                                </Button>
                            </Grid>
                            {window.innerWidth >= 1200 && (
                                <Grid item>
                                    <img src="/static/images/location.svg" width="450px" />
                                </Grid>
                            )}
                        </Grid>
                    </form>
                </Container>
            </Dialog>
        </div>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        editAddressData: state.UI.editAddress,
        specificAddressData: state.userDetail.specificAddress,
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        popClose: (data) => dispatch(editAddressAction(data)),
        updateAddress: (data, addressId) =>
            dispatch(updateAddressAction(data, addressId)),
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EditAddressDialog);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send all the default values when no input has been given, just change `defaultValue` to `value`. That way you will still be able to overwrite the values, but if you don't, the value given in your code will be send to the submit function.